# search bar with multiple values being delimited

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am using a searchbox to filter through results. The value of the search box is sent using ajax to the php file which performs the search. I'm trying to add several different features. The first part is delimiting values in the textbox separated by a whitespace. The values are put in an array and then a search is executed using a foreach loop for as many variables as there are in the array. It seems to be working, but because of the positioning of my print statement it is building two separate

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#srchbtn').click(function start(){
  getContacts();
 });
});
 
//functions from javascript --- functions.js
function getContacts(){
  var txtsearch = $('#txtsearch').val();
  $.ajax({
   url: 'contactstable.php',
   type: "POST",
   //dataType: "json",
   data: ({txtsearch: txtsearch}),
   success: function(response){
    $('#displayContacts').html(response);
    addRowHandlers();
   }
  });
  
 }
window.onload = getContacts();
```

```html
<div id="search">
 
<input type="text" name="txtsearch" size="30" id="txtsearch">
<button type="button" name="srchbtn" id="srchbtn">Search</button>
 
</div>
<div id="displayContacts">


</div>

contacts table php.

<?php

//**********************************************
//*
//*  Connect to MySQL and Database
//*
//**********************************************

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

tables. Is there a way to have everything on one table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like your issue is just that you seem to be completing the query multiple times and then building the HTML table in the same loop as when you find the query data.

what i suggest is declaring an array before entering the ForEach loop for your queries--then, once the query is complete, merge your first array ($totalResults) with the new results ($sqlResults); do this loop for all of your search terms like you were before.

after that, you can print your table!

```
//create a new array to store our results
$totalResults = array();

foreach ($search1 as $val)
{
    $outputDisplay = "";
    $myrowcount = 0;
    $sql_statement  = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, pcat, position, state ";
    //, congroup, cattype, company, position, email, website, phone, mphone, wphone, fax, add1, add2, city, state, zip, country, reference, entrydate, enteredby, notes ";
    $sql_statement .= "FROM contacts ";
    $sql_statement .= "WHERE (firstname LIKE '%$val%' or lastname LIKE '%$val%')"; 
    $sql_statement .= "ORDER BY lastname, firstname";
    $sqlResults = selectResults($db, $sql_statement);
    $error_or_rows = $sqlResults[0];
    if (substr($error_or_rows, 0 , 5) == 'ERROR')
    {
        $outputDisplay .= "<br />Error on DB";
        $outputDisplay .= $error_or_rows;
    }
    else
    {
        //results are good, so let's merge them into our main array and go in for another round
        $totalResults = array_merge($totalResults, $sqlResults);
    }
}
```

instead of relying on the "$error_or_rows" variable for our loop, it'd be better to just count the actual size of our totalResults since we're combining the arrays (using PHP's built in count() method)
here's the table printing code:

```
//since all of our data is in one array,
//we don't need to loop anymore.

$arraySize = $error_or_rows;
$outputDisplay .= '<table id="resultstable" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
$outputDisplay .= '<tr><th align="left">ID</th><th align="left" width="30%">First Name</th><th align="left" width="30%">Last Name</th><th align="left" width="30%">Pages Category</th><th align="left" width="30%">Position</th><th align="left" width="30%">state</th></tr>';

//still need to loop to build our table's rows though
for ($i=1; $i <= count($totalResults); $i++)
{
    $myrowcount++; //changed all of these values to "totalResults" instead of "sqlResults"
    $contactid = $totalResults[$i]['id'];
    $firstname = $totalResults[$i]['firstname'];
    $lastname = $totalResults[$i]['lastname'];
    $pcat      = $totalResults[$i]['pcat'];
    $position      = $totalResults[$i]['position'];
    $state     = $totalResults[$i]['state'];

    $outputDisplay .= '<tr>';
    $outputDisplay .="<td>".$contactid."</td>";
    $outputDisplay .= '<td><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$firstname.'</span></td>';
    $outputDisplay .= '<td><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$lastname.'</span></td>';
    $outputDisplay .= '<td><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$pcat.'</span></td>';
    $outputDisplay .= '<td><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$position.'</span></td>';
    $outputDisplay .= '<td><span style="font-size:10px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openCon()">'.$state.'</span></td>';

    $outputDisplay .= '<tr>';

}

//table is complete, let's close it and print it.
$outputDisplay .= "</table>";

print $outputDisplay;
```

Comment: Yes that resolves the issue thanks for your help! But now it is having toruble with the search, in my code i print the array out and it tells me what the values are being searched. It only searches for the first value, unless I add a white space. So Pari Mary searches only Pari where as Pari Mary'&nbsp' finds both but after that I cannot use more names.

Comment: i don't quite follow what the issue is. can you update your post with the most recent code changes?

Comment: Well previously when I would put in say two names in the search text box and post the value it would break it down into the array and have two searches hence printing out the table more than once. As you correctly pointed out it is because I was rebuilding the table each time. Now that I have changed the code, when I put more than one string the loop stops  before it reaches the last variable. For example pari lara will search pari not lara, even though my print statement shows two values. When I add a space after lara it searches both Pari and Lara (but it adds a result that shouldn't).

Comment: at page load search is empty so the array is at at [0]=>"" array count =1, at pari it is at [0]=> pari array count= 1; at pari mary array is at [01]=> pari [1]=>mary count=2 but it does not run the search for mary; at pari mary (blank space) array is at [0]=>pari [1]=>mary [2]=>blank and it runs both mary and pari however it adds an irrelevant search result that must have a space after it.

Comment: I will add a function to strip white spaces but the issue comes with the  for loop missing a value.

Comment: well, in the results display it looks like $i is starting at 1 (this is based off the code i gave you, so something i must've accidentally skipped over)

also, i still can't see the php code in the now-edited answer.

Comment: Ah, yes that worked, I thought I had made the change - but it gave me an issue still, I changed it from <= to just< and it worked just fine.

Comment: with any duplicate rows would I use a function to remove them from the sqlresults or the total results?

Comment: you'll probably want to remove them from the TotalResults array, since that's the one you use to display.